# sorting structures with multiple members c++

Tags: c++, class, sorting, structure

I would like to sort a class of "song" data types

```
class song{
  std::string artist;
  std::string title;
  std::string size;

  public:
};
```

I understand it is possible to use a bool operator to overload > but what if I want it to sort by artist, then by title, then by size, is there any way I can specify an order for comparison?

Comment: Since you will implement the overload for `<` You can have any criteria you desire. Whats stopping you?

Comment: Yes, you specify it in your `operator<`.

Answer (score 6):

When you create your `operator<` you specify the order of attributes you wish to use in the comparison.

Creating such operators is actually almost trivial with `boost::tie` (or `std::tie` if you are able to use C++11):

```
bool operator<(const song& left, const song& right)
{
    return boost::tie(left.artist, left.title, left.size) < boost::tie(right.artist, right.title, right.size);
}
```

Comment: thank you, Yeah I'm not allowed to use boost unfortunately since it is for school, but c++11 should be ok as long as I specify. Do you know how I would check on linux if I have c++11 libs and compiler installed?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions, either you have some sort of global variable [or similar] that you can access in the `operator>` function, or you use `sort` with a "compare function" argument.

The second solution would look something like this:

```
class song
{
    .... 
    static compareArtist(const song &a, const song &b)
    {
        return a.artist > b.artist;
    }
    static compareTitle(const song &a, const song &b)
    {
        return a.title > b.title;
    }
 ... 
}

if (sortby == artist)
   sort(songs.begin(), songs.end(), song::compareArtist);
else if (sortby == title)
   sort(songs.begin(), songs.end(), song::compareTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to assume you want a constant ordering based on multiple attributes. Instead interpreting your "then" as that you want to sort on different attributes at different times, here is an answer for that:

You can use std::sort with a lambda.

```
std::sort(songs.begin(), songs.end(), 
[](const Song& s1, const Song& s2)  
{
    // any comparison code you want.
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to overload `operator<` not `operator>`

```
bool operator<(const song& x, const song& y)
{
    if (x.artist < y.artist)
        return true;
    if (x.artist > y.artist)
        return false;
    if (x.title < y.title)
        return true;
    if (x.title > y.title)
        return false;
    if (x.size < y.size)
        return true;
    if (x.size > y.size)
        return false;
    return false;
}
```

There are any number of variations on this, but that works for me.

Comment: Actually, there are very few valid variations. Such a comparator must abide by the _strict weak ordering_ principle. Fortunately, as far as I can tell, yours does.